# postgres, linking libpq.so instead o libpq.so.5

Tags: postgresql

I installed rh-postgresql96 and rh-postgresql96-postgresql-devel on RH and I discovered that there is no libpq.so.5 but only libpq.so.

the point: I built my C++ binaries using PG, standard one not RH, and so the libpq.so.5  is linked.

questions 2 : is it possible to build linking libpq.so instead og libpq.so.5

Answer (score 0):

Usually those files with version numbers are just symlinks to the real shared object files.

Try to create a symlink manually - might just do the trick

`ln -s libpq.so libpq.so.5`